# Android - change layout with condition

Tags: android, dynamic, view, fragment, conditional-statements

I am making an app, where I have 10+ categories, but they would use kinda the same layout, but with different data shown in it. For easier understanding, I have categ1 and categ2, both of them uses the same fields, but with different data showing. I am new to android and I was thinking of making an activity and view for every category, but since I have about 12 of these, It might be tiring and I am not sure the memory management would be good if the app keeps open every page in it.

I would like to know any idea about which way might work out the best, but still easy for a newcomer? =) What I had in mind, but not sure how to do it is, when I click on a button for a category, it fires an intent with the "extra" string of the name of the category, so a page could load a dynamic view with that layout. Is this possible at all, and if yes, could someone explain it a bit? Including code is not needed! =)

In case It was too blurry what I said: You have X buttons for X categories, you click on a button, and it shows the page of that category. I would like to make this dynamic with only 1 layout, so when I click on the category, it loads the layout for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use like this...Simple all the best..

```
 if(condition 1) 
 {
     setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
 } else {
     setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
 }
```

Comment: Shall I use a fragment, or a simple activity with a layout? =)

Answer (score 0):

you can use fragment, what you need to do is pass the category as argument to the fragment when you creating it and then get argument in the fragment and display data in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I once had this question too and solved it with

```
switch (condition ){
            case 1:
                setContentView(R.layout. layout1);
                break ;
            case 2:
                setContentView(R.layout. layout2);
                break;
        }
```